# jquery slider ui question ("slide" vs "change" event..)

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

have following issue with jquery slider ui:

http://mayacove.com/dev/slider/slider2.html
slider works only when you drag handle, i.e., when you drag the slider the divs show and hide as expected (divs change as slider slides..)  but: if I CLICK on any point on slider instead of dragging, divs change ONLY if I click on a precise spot where a div is supposed to switch, otherwise div does not switch..  how do I fix this please??

( to make it simpler JS code is in slider2.html..)

thank you very much..

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any code in your change event. I would recommend both slide and change calling a separate function which handles the events, so something like;

```
$slider.slider({
    slide:  SlideChangeEvent,
    change: SlideChangeEvent
});

var SlideChangeEvent = function(e,ui){
  var currVal = Math.round((19500*ui.value)/100);
        $("#points-value").html(format(currVal));   
        for (i=0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
            if (ui.value == intervals[i]) { 
                $("#points-value").html(format(intervalsPoints[i]));
                $("#divs-to-show > div").hide();
                $("#divs-to-show > div").eq(i).show();
            }
        }
};
```

Sorry i haven't tested it though, no reason why it shouldn't work though i don't think.

Answer (score 0):

yes I know there's no code in my change event, because I don't know what code to put in there...!!  ;-)

unfortunately code you posted doesn't work..  even slider value doesn't change..

http://mayacove.com/dev/slider/slider2a.html

thank you...